# Can I use save summaries with tf.train.Supervisor using placeholders?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I am using a supervisor to manage my session, something like this:

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(
        logdir=logdir,
        summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all(),
        summary_writer=tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir),
        global_step=global_step,
        save_summaries_secs=60,
    )
```

The problem is that I defined my graph such that the data should be feed in using placeholders. How do I do this for the summaries created by the `save_summaries_secs` feature?

---

**Clarification**

The problem is that the supervisor runs all the summaries collected by `tf.summary.merge_all()` every (here) 60 seconds, without using a `feed_dict`. In order to calculate e.g. the loss I need to feed the data in somehow.

I can compute summaries manually with something like

```
sess.run(summary_op, feed_dict={...})
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand why using placeholders to pass in data is problematic. Does using scalar summaries such as `tf.summary.scalar("foo", some_tensorflow_scalar_op)` in your graph work?

Comment: I have updated the question, hope it is clearer now. And yes summaries do work

Answer (score 0):

The same problem for me ...... I just set `summary_op = None` and use `sv.summary_computed()` to report computed summaries manually.